# Can AutoIt write text into a field? For example into a input tag of a website?

Tags: bots, autoit

is it possible to write text into a text field with AutoIt? I cant find an answer to this.
I want my script to click into a text field and insert a number, is this possible? If yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can.
Take a look at `IE UDF`.
Check the help file for more details.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <IE.au3>

Local $oIE = _IE_Example("form")
Local $oElement = _IEGetObjByName($oIE, "textExample")
Sleep(1000)
$oElement.click ; this is not needed in order to set a value.
$oElement.value = "this is a test value"
```

In real world scenario you will probably be using `_IECreate` or `_IEAttach`.

Also there are other ways of doing this.

FOr example, you can focus an element, get a handle on IE control and do a ControlSend. The text will be sent to the focused element.

This is not desirable method since it relies on current focus and can be easily interrupted, hence its unreliable.

Comment: nice thanks! do you know if i can get a element by class?

Comment: Sure you can. List all elements using IETagNameGetCollection and search for the one with the desired class (If $oElem.classname == "someClass" Then )